# Why playground behaves strange. The below code is showing compiler error as well as shows the correct output while running the code

Tags: ios, swift

There is a func checkSum.I am invoking checkScope() before initializing sumation variable.If I invoke checkScope() again the code runs perfectly .

```
func checkScope (){
     sumation = 6
     print(sumation)
   }
checkScope()
var sumation = 5
checkScope()
```

Comment: How can you both get a compilation error _and_ be able to run the code?

Comment: In *real life* (in a project rather than in a Playground) the code doesn't compile.

Comment: check playgroud .

Comment: The project is compiling and giving the output .Thats a weird behaviour from swift .I dont know why it is happening

Comment: Yes, in a playground it behaves strange. Is this your question?

Comment: yes this is what i want to ask

Comment: Then mention that you mean the playground in your question. Clarity makes it easier for everyone and is a good way to avoid down votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Playground is so polite and executes the code although it's wrong. The reason is that unlike a Xcode project you can run code on the top level in a Playground.

In a project you will get a *Unresolved Identifier* compiler error.

The rule is: A variable must be declared and initialized (in the same scope) **before** being used.

Nevertheless the compiler error is shown in the Playground, too

[image]

Comment: yes compiler error is shown but output is also coming correct.Now I think it runs everything on top level so that might be the reason .Thanks for your help

Comment: *//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play*. The Playground environment is not as inexorable as the *real life* compiler 